# Displaying Selected values(Sql query) using c# and html

Tags: c#, html, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to display the data that is selected in the SQL query , I tried to use `ExecuteScalar()` but it only work with 1 value , here is my c# code :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=newSchool;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("view_profile", conn);
        cmd.CommandText = "exec view_profile @posted_id";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posted_id", WebForm1.x);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery;
        conn.Close();
```

and that's the proc :

```
CREATE PROC view_profile

@posted_in INTEGER
AS
BEGIN
SELECT P.poster , P.post_description
FROM Posts P
WHERE P.posted_in = @posted_in
END
```

Comment: please explain a bit more what problem are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are a little confused:

`ExecuteScalar()`: Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

`ExecuteNonQuery()`: Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected, it is intended for UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries

What you need is `ExecuteReader()`

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot , but another question please,if i want to display it in html,how can i do this?

Comment: @user3100088 there are hundreds of way. one is a databound control as the asp.net Repeater: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.ASPX It is too long to explain there. you can find thousands of examples online.